# Excel: Run-Time Error '13' Type Mismatch during a delete row execution

Tags: vba, excel

What would cause this line

`If Cells(i, 3) = "" Or VBA.Left(Cells(i, 3), 5) = "BIGA-" Or VBA.Left(Cells(i, 3), 5) = "BRNG-" Or VBA.Left(Cells(i, 3), 5) = "ENER-" Or VBA.Left(Cells(i, 3), 5) = "EURE-" Or VBA.Left(Cells(i, 3), 5) = "STRE-" Then Rows(i).Delete`

in the below macro to return a Run-Time Error '13' Type Mismatch after the first cell record is found and deleted?

```
Option Explicit

Sub deletedExceptions_row()
Dim i As Long
For i = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 3) = "" Or 
    VBA.Left(Cells(i, 3), 5) = "BIGA-" Or 
    VBA.Left(Cells(i, 3), 5) = "BRNG-" Or 
    VBA.Left(Cells(i, 3), 5) = "ENER-" Or 
    VBA.Left(Cells(i, 3), 5) = "EURE-" Or 
    VBA.Left(Cells(i, 3), 5) = "STRE-" Then
    Rows(i).Delete
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub deletedExceptions_row()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo whoa

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For i = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 3) = "" Or _
            VBA.Left(.Cells(i, 3), 5) = "BIGA-" Or _
            VBA.Left(.Cells(i, 3), 5) = "BRNG-" Or _
            VBA.Left(.Cells(i, 3), 5) = "ENER-" Or _
            VBA.Left(.Cells(i, 3), 5) = "EURE-" Or _
            VBA.Left(.Cells(i, 3), 5) = "STRE-" Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Exit Sub
whoa:
    MsgBox "Value of i is " & i, vbInformation, Err.Description
End Sub
```

Now does it give an error? If it does then what is the value of `i`. If the value of `i` is say 17 then check the cell C17. I am sure there is a formula in that cell which is giving an error. For example `#DIV/0!` or any other error. It is only in this scenario will it give a `type mismatch error`.

SNAPSHOT

[image]

Comment: What is the name of your sheet where you are testing it. Did you change `Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")` to the relevant sheet name? Replace "Sheet1" with the relevant sheetname.

Comment: yes and then it show me that value i is 7178 which was #NAME?  How would I modify this so that I can go and fix the error and then have it continue on?

Comment: Simply click "OK" on the message box. Go back to that cell and remove the error and then rerun the macro :)

Comment: Tip: Error Handling will always make your life easier ;)